# How to combine echo and find?

Tags: linux, bash

When I do the following `find` overrides `index.html` where I would have expected it would just append its results.

```
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head></body>" > index.html

find . -name "*.html" -exec echo "<a href=\"{}\">{}</a><br/>" \; >> index.html
```

It is suppose to find all html files and create an index of them.

Does anyone how to do this, ideally without using temp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your echo line, echo line should be:

```
echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head></body>' > index.html
```

You have `"` inside your text and in your echo command boundary as well.

Comment: I also think the `</body>` should be an oponing tag `<body>` and another `echo` in needed after the `find` to output the trail `</body></html>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape all " characters in echo.

```
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/></head></body>" > index.html

find . -name "*.html" -exec echo "<a href=\"{}\">{}</a><br/>" \; >> index.html
```